# JavaScript: differences between two ways of getting a random index from an array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

let's say we have an array with a size of n. I wanted to generate a random index i.e.  in the range of `[0, n - 1]`.

Here is what most of people would do

```js
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length))
```

However as I was grinding leetcode, I saw [this post](https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-delete-getrandom-o1/discuss/885744/JavaScript-Randomise-Solution-O(1)) in the discussion where it takes a different approach to generate the random index:

```js
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1e6+9)) % array.length;
```

I can understand why the second approach would work. **But I couldn't figure out exactly which one is preferable or in what situations one is better than the other.**

Comment: Just from the standpoint of readability, the second example is not very clear without having to think about it. I think this should be a deciding factor in many situations because you are likely not the only one to read your code.

Comment: Maybe it's trying to make it more random?

Comment: Yes agree with @evolutionxbox on "more random" (hence the upvote). However I doubt it is in practice. `Math.random() ` is the randomness. Multiplying that by a big number and then taking the modulus, doesn't introduce more randomness. Though likely, the 2nd example was it's author's thought process on "more"

Comment: The first way would be faster (less computation) and as equally random to the 2nd way

Comment: The fact they both use Math.random means they are going to be the same sort of distribution in the end. Someone was just being "cute".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on practical research there is no difference between the randomness of the two codes. Basically, they both are equally random.

I tried the codes below

**CODE 1**

```
let arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
let startTime = new Date().getTime() 
for(let i = 0;i<100000;i++){ 
  arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)]++ 
}
console.log(arr[0]+" "+arr[1]+" "+arr[2]+" "+arr[3]+" "+arr[4]+"
    "+arr[5]+" "+arr[6]) 
console.log(-startTime + new Date().getTime())
```

**CODE 2**

```
let arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
let startTime = new Date().getTime() 
for(let i = 0;i<100000;i++){ 
  arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e6+9)%7]++ 
}
console.log(arr[0]+" "+arr[1]+" "+arr[2]+" "+arr[3]+" "+arr[4]+"
    "+arr[5]+" "+arr[6]) 
console.log(-startTime + new Date().getTime())
```

Unsurprisingly, they both are equally random. You can plot them on https://www.rapidtables.com/tools/bar-graph.html

The first one was supposed to perform better but to my surprise, it **didn't**.

**So, you can use any of them, both will work exactly the same.**

Answer (score 0):

### Math.random():

[Details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random number in the range 0 to less than 1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1)
so the generated number will be like 0.523,0.23,0.13 ...

and multiply some number with random floating-point(<1) will return a number which is definitely lesser than itself

Math.random() can generate from `0` to `0.99999....`

### Option 1

So multiplying random() with array length will be a good approch

*Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length))*

### Option 2

Getting modulus (%) will also return a number that is definitely lesser than itself
so making a bigger number is not a good approach here

*Math.floor(Math.random() * (1e6+9)) % array.length;*